# Using jQuery to hide data on session expiry

Tags: jquery, session

I have built a simple countdown that mimics the timeout of my session in my application. The idea is that if the user leaves their computer for an extended period of time it will destroy all sessions and cookies as a failsafe and update the DOM with a different view e.g. a message saying that the session has expired. The reason for updating the DOM rather than doing a redirect is that the user could easily just hit the back button and see the previous page and all the data on it. However when doing it the DOM way the page source still shows the sensitive data!

Any ideas on the best way of changing the view in the browser and preventing a user from seeing the data in the history or on screen. I've currently opted for the AJAX route as it means getting around the other problems except the view source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery idle plugin and make an ajax request to destroy session when the timeout value is reached.

The plugin is here: http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/

Comment: That's NOT what I'm asking! I already have that functionality implemented. My question was that the browser history and page source still show the data previously viewed so a person could view it if the view the website via the back button.